# Django ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'settings'

Tags: python, django

### The Problem

When I try to run 'python manage.py runserver' I get this error:

```
    Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x1068ddc80>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aricliesenfelt/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/aricliesenfelt/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/aricliesenfelt/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 250, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/Users/aricliesenfelt/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/aricliesenfelt/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/aricliesenfelt/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/aricliesenfelt/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/aricliesenfelt/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Users/aricliesenfelt/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/aricliesenfelt/Desktop/scratch/django/django_tutorials/supplyai/ingest/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    import settings.py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'settings'
```

Here is my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^ingest/', include('ingest.urls'))
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

Here is my models.py where I am just trying to import the local settings.py file I have. Not the main settings.py file, but the one I made locally for this app.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL

import settings

DeclarativeBase = declarative_base()

def db_connect():
    return create_engine(URL(**settings.DATABASE))

def create_data_table(engine):
    DeclarativeBase.metadata.create_all(engine)

class Data(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'data'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    shipper_name = Column('shipper_name', String)
    seller_location = Column('seller_location', String)
    buyer_location = Column('buyer_location', String)
    product_category = Column('product_category', String)
    order_created_date = Column('order_created_date', String)

    def __init__(self, id, shipper_name, seller_location, buyer_location, product_category, order_created_date):
        self.id = id
        self.shipper_name = shipper_name
        self.seller_location = seller_location
        self.buyer_location = buyer_location
        self.product_category = product_category
        self.order_created_date = order_created_date
```

When I try to run the server, it is telling me that it cant find settings.py, but settings.py is literally in the same app that models.py is in. Not sure why this is happening. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Try using `from supplyai.ingest import settings`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You will need to import it using the full path. Try

```
from ingest import settings
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
import settings
```

with

```
from django.conf import settings
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom settings.py, please update the question with the folder structure and the filenames.

It's probably a problem with the folder structure of the python package, so basically import settings doesn't work because settings.py is not found from where the file is trying to import.

[Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#packages)

Answer (score -1):

```
"""
Load Settings from django
"""
def setup_settings():
    import os
    import django

    # Connect to the Django Database
    script_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']='<<YOUR_PROJECT>>.settings'
    django.setup()

def load_settings():

    from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured

    try:
        from django.conf import settings as settings
        settings.BASE_DIR <<<< Try to access one your settings
    except (ImproperlyConfigured, ModuleNotFoundError) as ex:
        print("Settings not loaded yet.. Load it now.")
        setup_settings()
        from django.conf import settings as settings
        settings.BASE_DIR
        print("BASE_DIR (%s) loaded." % settings.BASE_DIR)
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Could not load settings (%s)" % ex)

    if not hasattr(settings, 'BASE_DIR'):
        print("Could not find BASE_DIR in settings! ERROR!")
        sys.exit(1)

    return settings
```

Than in every file you just call this two lines:

```
import load_settings
settings = load_settings()
```